# Remove Ubuntu 11.04 partitions

Tags: 11.10, partitioning

I used to have Ubuntu 11.04. When 11.10 came out, I've made a fresh install, so I ended up with 2 Ubuntu's and one Win7 (on 2 disks);

I haven't realized that I could have pointed my 11.10 to the same swap the 11.04 was using, but that is besides the point, so I've ended up with 2 swap partitions each of 4Gb and 2 file systems for Ubuntu (30Gb and 40Gb). Obviously I want to remove 11.04 first because it eats up space, and second because it's obsolete for me now.

I just want to make sure I am following the right steps here.

1) Remove Ubuntu 11.04 from my grub loader (burg in my case); DONE.

2) Identify the 2 partitions (swap and filesystem) for 11.04 that need to be deleted: I have identified them in Disk Utility (both are on the same disk) as follows. Being on /dev/sdb they have the lowest number sdb1 and sdb2. Since I also have sdb4 and sdb5 (swap and filesystem) I assume they are for my newest Ubuntu 11.10. Also, another hint to it beeing the 11.04 is the fact that it's not mounted.

So, my questions are:

a) Is it safe to delete the 2 partitions? Have I identified them correctly?

b) Will my current numbering of sdb remain the same? Meaning that a new partition will allocate the number sdb1 again? Or is the number increasing constantly?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this one in the mean time.

1) Yes, I have identified the partitions correctly.

2) After removing the unnecessary partitions using gparted in a LiveCD (and unmounted the mounted drives), I have remade the numbering on the partitions:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```