# Deleted Windows Partitions on drive now what do I do?

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu and I figured it was time to learn. I am using Ubuntu server (headless?)

I have a drives as such:

```
    *-disk:1
         description: ATA Disk
         product: TOSHIBA MK1646GS
         vendor: Toshiba
         physical id: 1
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: LB11
         serial: 18MIT4Y8T
         size: 149GiB (160GB)
         configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=780ee5c1
```

I have deleted the partitions with help from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87563/remove-ubuntu-11-04-partitions) thread. Do I need to format after deleting the partitions?  Also, nice the drive is /dev/sbd I assume I need to mount it?

I'm a little lost at this point and could use a point in the right direction!!

Thanks all!

==== EDIT ====

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001eb47

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 316.6 GB, 316577677312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38488 cylinders, total 618315776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 3217 MB, 3217031168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 391 cylinders, total 6283264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x780ee5c1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdc: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x504bbe6a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question.

Comment: Done! ty for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You need to format the drive or partition before use. But before formatting, you need to create partitions on the disk.

Use GParted to do this easily in a graphical way. Go to /dev/sdb, format as ext4, and mount it to partition of your choosing, e.g. `/media/allthisfreespace`.

See the Ubuntu manual pages for [fdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//lucid/man8/fdisk.8.html), [mkfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mkfs.8.html), and [parted](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//lucid/man8/parted.8.html)

> I assume I need to mount it?

You can only mount the drive after creating a filesystem by formatting a partition.

Comment: awesome! that helped alot!